# Why is $\lor$ used in cases where xor is intended?

Tags: logic, notation, relations, predicate-logic

A binary relation $R$ on a set $X$ is trichotomous if the following is true:

$$\forall x,y \in X ([\neg(x <y) \land\neg(x=y) \land (x>y)] \lor [\neg(x <y) \land(x=y) \land \neg(x>y)] \lor [(x <y) \land\neg(x=y) \land \neg(x>y)])$$

At least, that's what [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)) said.

If they mean inclusive or by "$\lor$", then the above statement is incorrect. If they mean exclusive or, it is correct. However, I thought the notation for exclusive or was $\text{XOR}$ or $\oplus$, and that the notation for inclusive or was $\lor$.

Perhaps this is a case of differing notational conventions in different logics? If so, what logic was used in that article, and if xor is notated as $\lor$, what then is their notation for the inclusive or?

Just for clarity, using the notation the way I'm familiar with would yield this:

$$\forall x,y \in X ([\neg(x <y) \land\neg(x=y) \land (x>y)] \oplus [\neg(x <y) \land(x=y) \land \neg(x>y)] \oplus [(x <y) \land\neg(x=y) \land \neg(x>y)])$$

**EDIT:**

Not sure I get the explanations here.

I'll just elaborate on my understanding here, so as to maybe illuminate my misunderstanding:

$$(a = b) \lor (a \neq b)$$

This is wrong, because it opens up for the possibility of both $(a = b)$ and $(a \neq b)$ to be true at the same time, which is a contradiction. The inclusive or includes a possiblity here that's self-contradictory. That's my quarrel with the formula from the Wiki article. All of those three sub-formulae are in contradiction with each other, and thus, including the possibilities of several being true is wrong.

At least, that's how I see it.

Comment: There is no error. Just because a statement *can* be written with an exclusive disjunction doesn't mean that the inclusive disjunction is incorrect. For example, "$(A\wedge\neg B)\vee (\neg A\wedge B)$" and "$(A\wedge\neg B)\oplus (\neg A\wedge B)$" are equivalent - and the trichotomy principle is another (slightly more complicated) example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per your edit, you misunderstand what it means to assert an inclusive disjunction.

When we say "$X\vee Y$ is true" we do **not** mean "each of $X\wedge\neg Y$, $\neg X\wedge Y$, and $X\wedge Y$ is possible and one must be true" - we're simply asserting that either $X$ is true or $Y$ is true or both, leaving the door open to *further* assertions like "in fact $X\wedge Y$ does not hold" or "in fact $X$ holds outright."

It may arguably be **good pedagogical practice** to make the strongest assertion immediately justified by context, e.g. "$a=b\oplus a\not=b$" instead of "$a=b\vee a\not=b$," but it's not mathematically necessary to do so. (In fact in my opinion it's *not* good pedagogical practice, but that's a whole separate discussion.)

Comment: Thank you. I was starting to suspect this was my misunderstanding when discussing with @Ted. I asked him this very question, but before he could answer, you gave this answer. Thus, I accepted yours.

Comment: I think a reason why it is good practice to use $\lor$ as in the Wikipedia article is that the formula in which it is used is precisely the disjunctive normal form of the statement, "Exactly one of $x<y,$ $x=y,$ and $x>y$ is true."

Answer (score 8):

Using the inclusive "or" is correct here.

Notice that the conditions in brackets are like this: $[\neg(x <y) \land\neg(x=y) \land (x>y)]$, and similarly for the other two. So the conditions themselves already exclude the possibility that more than one of the $x>y$, $x=y$, $x<y$ happen, so the "or" symbol itself does not need to do the exclusion.

Additionally, $\oplus$ only means "exclusive or" for *two* elements. $A \oplus B \oplus C$ means "either exactly one, or all three" of $A, B, C$, and in general, $A_1 \oplus A_2 \oplus \ldots A_n$ means that an odd number of $A_i$'s are true (not exactly one), as you can easily check with the definition of xor.

---

**Addendum**. To be clear, that is to say: $$\rm A\oplus B\oplus C = (A\land\neg B\land\neg C)\lor(\neg A\land B\land\neg C)\lor(\neg A\land\neg B\land C)\lor(A\land B\land C)$$

But the trichotomy principle is expressed in the form of: $$\rm (A\land\neg B\land\neg C)\lor(\neg A\land B\land\neg C)\lor(\neg A\land\neg B\land C)$$

Because we do not want to admit $((x{\lt}y)\land(x{=}y)\land(x{\gt}y))$ as a possibility.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the square brackets? Do they function in a different way from normal parantheses? I just interpreted them as carving it up into sub-formulae that needed to be computed separately. I thought they were square simply for visual clarity.  This interpretation does not make the inclusive or correct here.

Comment: They are just for visual clarity: they are the same as normal parentheses. The inclusive "or" is correct, because the conditions are already mutually exclusive so it does not matter whether you use "inclusive or" or "exclusive or". Please think through it carefully.

Comment: Yes, but the fact that they are mutually exclusive means that the inclusive or is including possibilities that are self-contradictory.

Comment: $A \lor B$ means "at least one of $A$ or $B$ holds", period, no matter what $A$ or $B$ are. If that's the meaning I want, then using $\lor$ is correct, and whether it's possible for them to hold simultaneously (or even hold at all, for that matter) does not make using $\lor$ incorrect.

Comment: So, if I get you correctly, the notation works like this: a connective only needs to imply at least one possibility that is actually possible when $A$ and $B$ are taken into account. If the logical connective opens up for possibilities not possible given $A$ and $B$, it doesn't matter, so long as there are possibilites for which it holds. Is this correct?

Comment: Logical connectives don't know anything about the statements $A$ and $B$ they are connecting. When you write $A \lor B$, you are asserting that at least one of $A$ or $B$ holds, without knowing anything about the internals of $A$ or $B$.  Whether $A$ or $B$ or both or neither is actually possible doesn't affect the meaning of $\lor$.

Comment: "Logical connectives don't know anything about the statements A and B they are connecting." Penultimate nail in the coffin for my misunderstanding, thanks. However, one last uncertainty. You say "Whether A or B or both or neither is actually possible doesn't affect the meaning of ∨." The neither part here is what bothers me. You aren't saying that $(a \lor b) \land (\neg a \land \neg b)$ is possible, right? As in, the meaning of $lor$ stays the same no matter what, but the statement would still be false if both $a$ and $b$ were false?

Answer (score 1):

No, using inclusive or is correct:
The statement is: $$\forall x,y \in X ([\neg(x <y) \land\neg(x=y) \land (x>y)] \lor [\neg(x <y) \land(x=y) \land \neg(x>y)] \lor [(x <y) \land\neg(x=y) \land \neg(x>y)])$$
If you notice if any one of the three statements separated by $\lor$ is true then the other two are false,For instance if $ [\neg(x <y) \land\neg(x=y) \land (x>y)]$ is true then the other two are false since ,one of the other has $\neg(x>y)$ and the other has $(x <y)$.